# Prolog Flow Free game solver

Tags: prolog, logic

I have been trying to write a Flow free solver in Prolog. [Here is how the game looks like](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigduckgames.flow).
Prolog solver should find the solution for it. I have started doing something but I'm definitely missing some parts and not sure what to do next.
Here's what I have until now. As it is a homework question, I have had some parts provided for me, so they don't require any change.

```
:-include(entradaFlow9).
:-dynamic(varNumber/3).
symbolicOutput(0).

writeClauses:-
   atleastOneColorPerNode,
   atmostOneColorPerNode,
   atmost1Connected,
   atmost2Connected.

atleastOneColorPerNode:- 
   size(N), 
   between(1,N,I), 
   between(1,N,J), 
   between(1,N,K),
   findall( x-I-J-K, between(1,N,J), C ), 
   writeClause(C), 
   fail.
atleastOneColorPerNode.

atmostOneColorPerNode:- 
   size(N), 
   between(1,N,I), 
   between(1,N,J), 
   between(1,N,K1),    
   between(1,N,K2),
   K1<K2, 
   writeClause([ \+x-I-J-K1, \+x-I-J-K2 ] ), fail.
atmostOneColorPerNode.

atmost1Connected:- 
   c(I1,X1,Y1), 
   c(I2,X2,Y2), 
   I1 < I2, 
   size(N), 
   between(1,N,H),    
   distance((X1,Y1), (X2,Y2), X), X is 1, I2 is I1,
   writeClause( [\+r-I1-H, \+r-I2-H] ), fail.
atmost1Connected.

atmost2Connected:- 
   c(I1,X1,Y1), 
   c(I2,X2,Y2), 
   c(I3,X3,Y3), 
   I1 < I2, I2 < I3, 
   size(N),
   between(1,N,H), 
   distance((X1,Y1), (X2,Y2), X), X is 1, 
   distance((X1,Y1), (X3,Y3), Y), Y is 1, 
   I2 is I1, I3 is I2, 
   writeClause( [\+o-I1-H, \+o-I2-H, \+o-I3-H] ), fail.
atmost2Connected.


displayFlow(M).


% ========== No need to change the following: =====================================

main:- symbolicOutput(1), !, writeClauses, halt. % escribir bonito, no ejecutar
main:-  assert(numClauses(0)), assert(numVars(0)),
    tell(clauses), writeClauses, told,
    tell(header),  writeHeader,  told,
    unix('cat header clauses > infile.cnf'),
    unix('picosat -v -o model infile.cnf'),
    unix('cat model'),
    see(model), readModel(M), seen, displaySol(M),
halt.

var2num(T,N):- 
    hash_term(T,Key), 
    varNumber(Key,T,N),!.
var2num(T,N):- 
    retract(numVars(N0)), N is N0+1, 
    assert(numVars(N)), 
    hash_term(T,Key),
assert(varNumber(Key,T,N)), 
    assert( num2var(N,T) ), !.

writeHeader:- 
    numVars(N),
    numClauses(C),
    write('p cnf '),write(N), write('  '),write(C),nl.

countClause:-  
   retract(numClauses(N)), N1 is N+1, 
   assert(numClauses(N1)),!.

writeClause([]):- symbolicOutput(1),!, nl.
writeClause([]):- countClause, write(0), nl.
writeClause([Lit|C]):- w(Lit), writeClause(C),!.
w( Lit ):- symbolicOutput(1), write(Lit), write(' '),!.
w(\+Var):- var2num(Var,N), write(-), write(N), write(' '),!.
w(  Var):- var2num(Var,N),           write(N), write(' '),!.
unix(Comando):-shell(Comando),!.
unix(_).

readModel(L):- 
   get_code(Char), 
   readWord(Char,W), 
   readModel(L1), 
   addIfPositiveInt(W,L1,L),!.
readModel([]).

addIfPositiveInt(W,L,[N|L]):- 
   W = [C|_], between(48,57,C), 
   number_codes(N,W), N>0, !.
addIfPositiveInt(_,L,L).

readWord(99,W):- 
    repeat, 
    get_code(Ch), 
    member(Ch,[-1,10]), !, 
    get_code(Ch1),     
    readWord(Ch1,W),!.

readWord(-1,_):-!, fail. %end of file
readWord(C,[]):- member(C,[10,32]), !. % newline or white space marks end of word
readWord(Char,[Char|W]):- get_code(Char1), readWord(Char1,W), !.
```

The data I have is:

```
size(9).
c(blue,    9,1,  2,2).
c(brown,   3,1,  8,4).
c(red,     3,4,  1,7).
c(cyan,    1,8,  4,4).
c(green,   1,9,  5,2).
c(yellow,  7,7,  7,9).
c(pink,    6,5,  8,7).
c(violet,  8,9,  9,6).
c(orange,  5,8,  8,8).
```

Comment: What is your question? You just stated what you've got so far. Is there a _specific_ problem you're stuck with?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to define and differentiate where the point has only one color connection(starting ending points) and a point which has 2 connections.

Comment: If you want, you can add an image, for illustration pourposes. https://lh3.ggpht.com/W4Q8dd8zjpdYe1KyV2t56QjJ_qgq299FzyGs4sZpFl50-vJ2SFNjM3cA1BGU32jqRp0=w300-rw